# CT scan software

Tags: computers, medical-imaging, ct-scans

I'm looking for software (free or budget) to analyze CT scans of pigs. I need to find the volume of the lungs, in normal situations and during pneumothorax (laprosopic surgery). The problem I'm having is distinguishing the lungs from heart/backbone etc. under high intrapleural pressure.

Software I already have is: Osirix and Matlab

[image]

Comment: How are pneumothorax and laparoscopic surgery related to each other in your question?

Comment: I think air is injected to create pneumothorax before laparascopic surgery to create space for instruments.

Comment: It will be helpful to post here a slice of CT image with pneumothorax. If the area can be determined in each slice, they can be added together to give an idea of the volume. So if someone knows software for the area, you can get the volume.

Comment: This question has already been asked on stackoverflow.com -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484577/volume-render-dicomdir-ct-scan/3671228#3671228

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for [apps or software is off-topic](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/384/114) and should be asked at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.